# How can I count the number of projects in eclipse workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, statistics

I have a workspace that has a lot of projects in it. Does eclipse provide statistics on the projects of the workspace? I could just count the number of directories, but I don't think it's not accurate as only some of the directories might be imported as projects in eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the first project in your *Package Explorer* Eclipse view, then press shift and click on the last project.  You will see the project count at the bottom of the window.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a Linux/Unix environment, cd to your workspace and use:

```
 find . -name ".project"
```

Comment: you mean something like 'find . -name ".project" | wc -l' :)

Comment: For a windows equivilent you can do dir /s *.project.